# how to show product list using simple slider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, product, flutter-listview, fluttermap

[This is the task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmUfm.png)
the task is whenever slider is use where slider value is product price only product show under the slider value.....

ex - if slider value is 20000 then show only product under the 20000 price.
I want to do this with map method in flutter.

the task is whenever slider is use where slider value is product price only product show under the slider value.....

ex - if slider value is 20000 then show only product under the 20000 price.
I want to do this with map method in flutter.

```
enter code here

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int i = 0;
  double _value = 0;
  List a = [];
  List product = [
    {'id': '1', 'name': 'Watch', 'price': '3200', 'category': 'wearable'},
    {'id': '2', 'name': 'T-Shirt', 'price': '520', 'category': 'wearable'},
    {'id': '3', 'name': 'Jeans', 'price': '840', 'category': 'wearable'},
    {
      'id': '4',
      'name': 'refrigerator',
      'price': '1800',
      'category': 'wearable'
    },
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          "Products Filter",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Slider(
              min: 0,
              max: 80000,
              onChanged: (double value) {
                setState(() {
                  i++;
                  _value = value;
                  // if (product[1]['price'] < _value) {
                    a.add(product);
                  
                });
              },
              value: _value,
            ),
            Text(
              "All Products < Rs. ${_value.toInt()}",
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20)),
            Column(
              children: a.map((e) {
                return Container(
                  height: 80,
                  width: w,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [Text(product[i]['id'])],
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 0)),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(product[i]['name']),
                            Text(product[i]['category'])
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(product[i]['price']),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please share your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a condition in your map:

```
product.map((e) {
                if (double.parse(e['price']) < _value) { 
                return YourWidget()
                }
                return Container() 
}
```

And you'll need to change your setState and just remove the `a.add(product)` line

Full code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  double _value = 0;
  List product = [
    {'id': '1', 'name': 'Watch', 'price': '3200', 'category': 'wearable'},
    {'id': '2', 'name': 'T-Shirt', 'price': '520', 'category': 'wearable'},
    {'id': '3', 'name': 'Jeans', 'price': '840', 'category': 'wearable'},
    {
      'id': '4',
      'name': 'refrigerator',
      'price': '1800',
      'category': 'wearable'
    },
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          "Products Filter",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Slider(
              min: 0,
              max: 80000,
              onChanged: (double value) {
                setState(() {
                  _value = value;
                });
              },
              value: _value,
            ),
            Text(
              "All Products < Rs. ${_value.toInt()}",
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20)),
            Column(
              children: product.map((e) {
                if (double.parse(e['price']) < _value) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 80,
                    width: w,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [Text(e['id'])],
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 0)),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 2,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [Text(e['name']), Text(e['category'])],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text(e['price']),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }
                return Container();
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: nosuchmethod error showing ...can you edit my code????//

Comment: Just edited my answer with full code and a little fix on your case where we need to parse the value to double because it's a String

Comment: T#@nx man .......